# How do I parse user input from the standard input stream?

Tags: c++, input

I'm writing a very simple program where I want to get user input from the standard input stream (keyboard) and then do something based on what input I encountered.  However, the problem is that sometimes the input will be a number (double) while othertimes it'll be a string. I'm not sure exactly what methods calls I need in order to parse it properly (perhaps something similar to Integer.parseInt in java).

Here is some pseduocode of what I would like to do:

```
cin >> input
if(input is equal to "p") call methodA;
else if(input is a number) call methodB;
else call methodC;
```

Comment: What is `input`? `char` or `std::string`?

Comment: I'm not sure...whatever would make this program easiest to implement...So string I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void a(string& s){ cout << "A " << s << endl; }
void b(double d){ cout << "B " << d << endl; }
void c(string& s){ cout << "C " << s << endl; }

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "p")
        a(input);
    else
    {
        istringstream is;
        is.str(input);
        double d = 0;
        is >> d;
        if (d != 0)
            b(d);
        else
            c(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
if(input =="p") f();
else if(is_number(input)) g();
else h();
```

Now implement `is_number()` function:

```
bool is_number(std::string const & s)
{
  //if all the characters in s, are digits, then return true;
  //else if all the characters, except one, in s are digits, and there is exactly one dot, then return true;
  //else return false
}
```

Implement this function yourself, as it seems to be homework. You can also consider case like the number may begin with sign `+` or `-`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution I use is to read the input as a line (using
`std::getline` rather than `>>`), and parse it as I would in any
language—`boost::regex` is very useful here; if you are sure that
you can count on C++11, it's `std::regex` (which I think is almost
identical to Boost).  So you end up with something like:

```
std::string line;
if ( ! std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) {
    //   Error reading line (maybe EOF).
} else {
    if ( regex_match( line, firstFormat) ) {
        processFirstFormat( line );
    } else if ( regex_match( line, secondFormat) ) {
        processSecondFormat( line ) ;
    } ...
}
```

Comment: `if( !std::string( std::cin, line ) )`? You mean `if (! std::getline( std::cin, line )`?

Comment: @Nawaz Definitely.  I'll edit the post to fix it.  (I think that's called a thinko.  Rather like a typo, but on a bigger scale.)